# Check for Date in Datespan for multiple times

Tags: r

i have data that looks like this:

```
Data <- "Person Address Starting.Date  Resignation.Date Job
 John         abc       01.01.2017    03.01.2017        IT      
  Sarah        cde      06.01.2017 06.07.2017       Teacher
  Susi         bfg     09.06.2017  08.09.2017     secretary"
Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

My goal is to find out how long people stayed in their job before quitting and put that information in a new variable. So i check if the resignation date is in a certain datespan, what I do by using this Code:

```
Data$Span<- ifelse(Data$Resignation.Date>= "01.01.2017" & Data$Resignation.Date <= "31.01.2017", 1, 
                              ifelse(Data$Resignation.Date>= "01.02.2017" & Data$Resignation.Date <= "28.02.2017", 2,
                                     ifelse(Data$Resignation.Date>= "01.03.2017" & Data$Resignation.Date <= "31.03.2017", 3,
                                            ifelse(Data$Resignation.Date>= "01.04.2017" & Data$Resignation.Date <= "30.04.2017", 4,
                                                   ifelse(Data$Resignation.Date>="01.05.2017" & Data$Resignation.Date <= "31.05.2017",5, 
                                                          ifelse(Data$Resignation.Date>="01.06.2017" & Data$Resignation.Date<="30.06.2017",6, 
                                                                 ifelse(Data$Resignation.Date>="01.07.2017" & Data$Resignation.Date<="31.07.2017",7, 
                                                                        ifelse(Data$Resignation.Date>="01.08.2017" & Data$Resignation.Date<="31.08.2017", 8,
                                                                               ifelse(Data$Resignation.Date>="01.09.2017" & Data$Resignation.Date<="30.09.2017", 9,
                                                                                      ifelse(Data$Resignation.Date>="01.10.2017" & Data$Resignation.Date<="31.10.2017",10,
                                                                                             ifelse(Data$Resignation.Date>="01.11.2017" & Data$Resignation.Date<="30.11.2017", 11,
                                                                                                    ifelse(Data$Resignation.Date>="01.12.2017" & Data$Resignation.Date<="31.12.2017",12,999))))))))))))
```

The data I presented is for a subset for People who started working in January. I have subsets for all 12 months in 2017. What I want to do is use the same Code for People who started working in February / March / and so on. To do this I would have to alter the Code in that it starts with the first line and adds one month and then adds one month for all following lines. So that for example for the February subset it would start with

```
Data$Resignation.Date>= "01.02.2017" & Data$Resignation.Date <= "28.02.2017.2017", 1,
```

and end with

```
 ifelse(Data$Resignation.Date>="01.01.2018" & Data$Resignation.Date<="31.01.2018",12,999
```

Is there any way to do this without copy pasting the Code and doing the changes manually for every month? Since the changes follow a certain systematic I would think that it would be possible, but I could not find any solution for this. I looked for Solutions in the dplyr package since I thought that my Problem fits there, but that did not help me. I would be very thankful for any advice. Of Course I will happily answer remaining questions.

P.S.: I am not not attached to using the subsets, that was just easier for me to work with since I am not so experienced in r. I filtered the subsets by using this Code

```
Data <- TotalData[TotalData$Starting.Date>= "01.01.2017" & TotalData$Starting.Date <= "31.01.2017",]
```

Comment: so you want people who has joined and left in the same month to be coded right,, for example a person joined in December 2018 and also left in December 2018 so you want it to be coded as 12 am i right?

Comment: Ah no sorry, i want to Code how Long they stayed in the Company so that Person should be coded as 1 for one month (since the People have one month notice this Person should have started on the 1st and left on the 31st).

Comment: sorry it is still not clear what you want  output as code of 1 to 12 or you need tenure of the person ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should be sufficient to do your work :-
Logic is if the Start date and end data are same it will give you 1and if they are not same it will give you months difference for how many months an employee was there for a company

```
library(lubridate)

Data$Starting.Date <- dmy(Data$Starting.Date)
Data$Resignation.Date <- dmy(Data$Resignation.Date)

Data$code<- ifelse(month(Data$Starting.Date) == month(Data$Resignation.Date),1,(interval(Data$Starting.Date, Data$Resignation.Dat) %/% months(1)))
```

Data :-

```
Data <- structure(list(Person = structure(1:4, .Label = c("John", "johnyy", 
"Sarah", "Susi"), class = "factor"), Address = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("abc", "bfg", "cde"), class = "factor"), 
    Starting.Date = structure(c(17167, 17199, 17172, 17326), class = "Date"), 
    Resignation.Date = structure(c(17169, 17199, 17353, 17417
    ), class = "Date"), Job = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("IT", 
    "secretary", "Teacher"), class = "factor"), code = c(1, 2, 
    999, 999)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with the lubridate package to get the time a person stayed in the company.

```
library(lubridate)
Data <- "Person Address Starting.Date  Resignation.Date Job
 John         abc       01.01.2017    03.01.2017        IT      
 Sarah        cde      06.01.2017 06.07.2017       Teacher
 Susi         bfg     09.06.2017  08.09.2017     secretary"
Data <- read.table(text=Data, header = TRUE)

Data$Starting.Date = dmy(Data$Starting.Date)
Data$Resignation.Date = dmy(Data$Resignation.Date)


time.interval <- Data$Starting.Date %--% Data$Resignation.Date
time.period <- as.period(time.interval)
time.period <- month(time.period)
Data$Span <- time.period
```